# RSpec : Multiple scenarii for same context

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

How to create multiple scenarii without to have to reinit context between 2 tests with RSpec ? I don't need context reinitialisation (that is very slow), but I need to check multiple things for the same given context.  The example below works, but it's a bad example : the context is reinitialized. If I do before(:all), it doesnt works because of the stubs. Any idea ?

```
feature 'Aids page' do 

  context 'No active user' do
    before(:each) do
      create_2_different_aids
      disable_http_service
      visit aids_path
    end
    after(:each) do
      enable_http_service
    end
    scenario 'Should display 2 aids NOT related to any eligibility' do
      display_2_aids_unrelated_to_eligibility
    end
    scenario 'Should not display breadcrumb' do
      expect(page).not_to have_css('.c-breadcrumb')
    end

  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

feature specs often have more than one expect in the same scenario. They are not like unit tests where each `it` should test only one thing... they are more like what a user actually does on a page: "go here, click on this thing, check I can see that thing, click there, check that the thing changes" etc... so you can just do something like this:

```
feature 'Aids page' do 

  context 'No active user' do
    scenario 'Sees aids not related to eligibility' do
      create_2_different_aids
      disable_http_service
      visit aids_path

      expect(page).not_to have_css('.c-breadcrumb')
      display_2_aids_unrelated_to_eligibility

      enable_http_service
    end
  end
end
```

Alternatively... it's possible to use either shared setup (as you have already done). That is fairly common.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I don't completely agree here, each test should test only one thing, no matter it is categorized "unit" or "integration" or "whatever" test. Without the ability to explicit what is the test about, we end up with a mess of expectations that do not make sense for a newcomer.

Comment: feature specs aren't unit-tests - they are more like integration tests. This is how they are supposed to be written. I've been working with these for a long time now (I've been using Rails professionally since May 2005) - including with a lot of newcomers, who have never had a problem with it once its been explained how they are supposed to work. Integration-style tests are supposed to emulate the way a real user really uses the system. They don't get confusing if written correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Found. Actually there is a hack you can use to initialize your test only once, as the example shown below :

```
feature 'Aides page' do 

  context 'No active user' do
    that = nil
    before do
      if !that
        create_2_different_aids
        disable_http_service
        visit aides_path
        that = Nokogiri::HTML(page.html)
      end
    end
    after do
      enable_http_service
    end
    scenario 'Should display 2 aids NOT related to any eligibility' do
      display_2_aids_unrelated_to_eligibility(that)
    end
    scenario 'Should not display breadcrumb' do
      expect(that.css('.c-breadcrumb').size).to eq(0)
    end
  end

end
```